# aliasing python scripts on windows

Tags: python, windows, alias

I can run my helpful scripts in linux by using `alias useful "python ~/scripts/useful.py"` but I can't work out how to do this in windows. My scripts use `argparse` and so solutions like [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1116204/227126) (I've added `scripts` to the path so I can then use `useful arg1 arg2 ...`)  don't work, the script only receives the first argument (filename).

I want to be able to run the command `useful arg1 arg2` under windows like I can in linux.

Comment: If you're not seeing `arg1` and `arg2` in `sys.argv`, then the .py file association is misconfigured. Don't assume that the answer to which you've linked is anywhere near complete. `assoc` and `ftype` have no bearing at all on the shell's selected ProgId. Also, they only show and modify a subset of system associations defined for all users in `HKLM\Software\Classes`.

Comment: But in the documentation for those commands, it gives an example:
    
`and the script could be invoked as follows: script 1 2 3`
then this should work right?

Comment: If the directory containing useful.py is in `Path` and .PY is in `PathExt`, then `useful arg1 arg2` will (should) work.

Comment: All of the above is true. The command `useful arg1 arg2` does not work

Comment: Begin by inspecting your current user choice `ProgId` for .py files, defined in the registry key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice`.

Comment: The ProgId is `Applications\python.exe` should I change this to `C:\anaconda2\python.exe`?

Comment: That's an automatically created entry. Rename the ".py" key under `...\Explorer\File‌​Exts` to ".py_bak". Next, right-click a .py file and select to choose another app on the open-with menu. Select a "Python" entry with the snakes icon, and select the box to always use this app and click ok. Refresh regedit (F5) and check `...\File‌​Exts\.py\UserChoice` again. Is the ProgId set to `Python.File`?

Comment: No it's set to `py_auto_file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128639/discussion-between-lucidnonsense-and-eryksun).